# Neo4j ServerPlugin Configuration

Tags: neo4j

I'm building a Neo4J Server plugin. I'd like to have some configuration values that I can manually set in neo4j.properties or neo4j-server.properties and then the plugin can read and utilize these value. How can I access config values from a ServerPlugin?

Clarification:
I'd really like something that will work across future releases of Neo4J, so something that is part of the public API and is not deprecated would be best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Neo4j's internal dependency mechanism, you can access a instance of `Config` (https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/master/community/kernel/src/main/java/org/neo4j/kernel/configuration/Config.java). This class gives you access to the configuration.

Take the following untested snippet as a guideline:

```
...
import org.neo4j.kernel.configuration.Config
...

@Description( "An extension to the Neo4j Server accessing config" )
public class ConfigAwarePlugin extends ServerPlugin
{
    @Name( "config" )
    @Description( "Do stuff with config" )
    @PluginTarget( GraphDatabaseService.class )
    public void sample( @Source GraphDatabaseService graphDb ) {
        Config config = ((GraphDatabaseAPI)graphDb).getDependencyResolver().resolveDependency(Config.class);

        // do stuff with config
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This does work, but I'd like something that might be supported going forward. 

1)The GraphDatabaseAPI interface is deprecated with a message "This will be moved to internal packages in the next major release." 

2)The getDependencyResolver method has a message of "Usage of this method is generally an indication of architectural error." 

3) The Config.getParams method has a TODO in the code of "Get rid of this, to allow us to have something more elaborate as internal storage (eg. something that can keep meta data with properties)."

I'm concerned about the longevity of this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I use `Properties`:

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    try
    {
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("./conf/neo4j.properties");
        props.load(in);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        try
        {
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("./neo4j.properties");
            props.load(in);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e2)
        {
            logger.warn(e2.getMessage());
        }
        catch (IOException e2)
        {
            logger.warn(e2.getMessage());
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        logger.warn(e.getMessage());
    }
    String myPropertyString = props.getProperty("myProperty");
    if (myPropertyString != null)
    {
        myProperty = Integer.parseInt(myPropertyString);
    }
    else
    {
        myProperty = 100;
    }
```

and in `neo4j.properties` I have:

```
...    
# Enable shell server so that remote clients can connect via Neo4j shell.
#remote_shell_enabled=true
# Specify custom shell port (default is 1337).
#remote_shell_port=1234

myProperty=100
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd have the same concern you have partially addressed in your code which is where the server is started from and trying to load neo4j.properties from a relative path.